# Changing an Image's alpha through an animation in Unity

Tags: unity, animation

I'm trying to change an `Image`'s alpha through a legacy animation in Unity, so that it fades in and out in a loop. The animation works: I can see the color updated in realtime in the *inspector*. But the `Image` is not actually being updated. I know that it is possible this way, since changing the alpha manually in the inspector does change the opacity of the `Image`.

I could write a script for this, but would prefer to do it through an animation.

Comment: What shader are you using to render?

Comment: @Jon As far as I know, [`Image`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) does not have a shader. And I think I know what you're getting at. It's capable of using the alpha channel: I'm drawing a png with transparent regions.

Comment: @Jon Aha, didn't think of that. But I'm not using any material, my `Image` is simply a `Sprite`. Changing the material to Sprite-Default doesn't work either.

Comment: I tested this, and it works for me.  I created a Canvas, then I created an Image, then I created an animation and set the Color value to alpha 0.  Ran it, and the Image dissapears as expected.  Can you post a screenshot of your setup maybe?

http://i.imgur.com/W6uDMsf.gif

Comment: @Jon Ah, but that's the new animation system, if I'm not mistaken. I'm using the legacy system. Guess I'll have to get familiar with that one then

Comment: Ok sorry, I wasn't aware that there is a different animation system available.  Might not be compatible, sorry I don't know.